# Get all <option>s from <select> using getElementById

Tags: php, html, domdocument

I need to get all of the `<option>` data from a `<select>` in an HTML document using PHP. The code that I have at the moment:

```
$pageData = $this->Http->get($this->config['url']);
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$this->Dom->loadHTML($pageData);
$select = $this->Dom->getElementById('DDteam');
```

I am not sure how, from here, to get the value of each of the options and also the text inside the option tags. I can't inspect the object using `print_r` or similar either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use the DOM-API to retrieve the data you want. Since the `<select>` element is not that complex you can fetch all the `<options>`-nodes using [`getElementsByTagName`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.getelementsbytagname.php):

```
$select = $this->Dom->getElementById('DDteam');
$options = $select->getElementsByTagName('option');

$optionInfo = array();
foreach($options as $option) {
    $value = $option->getAttribute('value');
    $text = $option->textContent;

    $optionInfo[] = array(
        'value' => $value,
        'text' => $text,
    );
}

var_dump($optionInfo);
```